# In ArcGIS, exporting a GRIB file to a different format changes the cell values of the original raster

Tags: export, raster-conversion, grib, arcgis-10.7

I downloaded some climate variables from Copernicus as GRIB format. ArcGIS 10.7.1 allows me to directly add them to my table of contents and it shows me, as usual, some maximum and minimum values. The problem is that when I try to export them to a different format, the new raster (I tried to convert them to Tif and Geodatabase file) presents different values compared to the one originally imported. For instance, if the original file presents max and min values of 86.11 and 37.36, respectively, the converted raster (in any format) presents values that range from 97.64 to 10.46! What am I doing wrong?

Thanks for your time!

Comment: Have you checked that the values are actually different? Use the identify tool and click a few pixels to check.  You probably have approximate min/max statistics showing which can be different even though the  raster values haven't changed (unless you used lossy compression in the output tif/gdb raster).

Comment: Apparently, export data used compression of 75% which changed my data. Instead, I used the copy raster tool and now everything is fine! Thanks!